# Cartoon: 4 kids transform into video game characters to save the world from a hacker and an evil program

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, video-games, super-hero, virtual-worlds

There are 4 friends: 2 girls and 2 boys who play video games. A virus program escapes and, with the help of a programmer boy, transforms the world into a video game. But a good program in a white robe turns the four of them into video game characters to save the world.

The evil virus mostly looked like The Tick from the cartoon "The Tick". Big strong guy with muscles but in red spandex. Little head with antenas, BIG chin and evil mustache.

One hero is the typical blonde girl who can scream loudly with a microphone or headphones. The other chick was shorter, more a grumpy type and with her big metal boots she was able to rock / shake the ground. There was also a funny white boy with red hair, he was a cyber archer. And their black-skinned friend, a typical tech guy with maybe one laser eye.

The transformed world has always had a theme: a swamp, a volcano,  space, a cyber city, a sewer, once a pinball machine, and so on.
For some game points they were able to summon different vehicles, weapons and reinforcements/buffs.

The story is made up of the usual repetitive events: every day the hacker guy transforms the world or just the city with a wicked program. Summoning new monsters and obstacles for stopping the good guys to defeat him. 
But our heroes always win and the evil program comments what a loser he is and the guy get frustrated.

(In the end, they convince the hacker guy that it just using him and he chose the good side then they wiped out the evil program forever.) - NOPE XD

Not Code Lyoko, ReBoot, Linkers, Cyberchasers. There is no 3D; it was fully hand drawn. I think it was American, but was definitely not Japanese and there was no anime-like stuff. I was young when I saw it, i'm live in a foreign country Hungary. So i dont know when was it released, but maybe before 2005. The main group maybe has something "force" in their name.

Comment: Do you remember the name of this in your language? What country did you see it in?

Comment: Im from Hungary and i dont know what was it name at all.

Comment: Huh, looks like [Barbie Video Game Hero](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6185658/) may have ripped this idea off.

Comment: This is a series, right? Not a cartoon movie?

Comment: @MarkHenderson: If user25730 is correct, it might be a case of cross-pollination. MP4orce's director, Michael Hefferson, also did work on Barbie films.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like *[MP4orce](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP4orce)*? Heard about it in relation to *ReBoot: The Guardian Code*, in which teens are beamed into cyberspace to battle hackers and viruses. Ironically, the basis for both shows sounds identical, apart from *ReBoot: The Guardian Code* featuring 3D CGI, and *MP4orce* appearing not to (from a brief glance).

From the translated Wikipedia page of 2006 German series:

> The four friends Cooder, Kayce, Laylen and Benny are drawn into the world of a computer game . There they develop their superpowers through music and fight together against the evil plans of DELVAN 13.

### Opening Credits

Comment: Definitely SEEMS to be the answer based on the OP's description. And that bad guy definitely looks like an evil version of The Tick. Great find!

Comment: Thank you! This is it :D